# How can you permanently disable palette and component tree in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, i3

I have a problem because I am using a tiling window manager, everytime I open an XML file, in Android studio, then these two small windows open op and block my view of the code. I don't know how I can permanently disable the windows/toolbars/view, (or what you call them)

I use `Mod+Q` to exit them every time I open the XML file, and it is quite tiring, so I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of these useless panels for goods :-)

I already searched alot in the settings of android studio, and I tried to click *remove from sidebar* and I even found out that you can click `Shift+Escape` to hide it, but my fingers gets tired from all this extra clicking everytime I enter XML split mode... :-)

Please Help Me - and thanks in advance! :-)

[image: view of how the windows look when they pop up everytime i open an XML file]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the title, and click on attached side

then left

then you can minimize it

Comment: Thank you Alireza. But I want to get rid of them and never see them again. My problem is that they return every time I enter the XML file.

Comment: @mama even if you hide them by  minimize  icon, they will be back to screen  every time you enter any xml file ?!

Comment: No, they return everytime. Even if I have to windows open and I click between the windows, then the panels pop up. It is unbearable :'D

Comment: from file -> invalidate cashes / restart -> invalidate And restart
if your problem not solved, delete this folder :
c:\user\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX, it will clear android studio  setting, then reset it
android studio will not remove.

Comment: No it is still the same. I don't use windows btw.